# Subtracting Dates to get Days in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 columns date_1 (*dtype('O')*) and date_2(*dtype(')*

```
date_1            date_2
2018-06-06        2018-04-01
```

when i do subtraction to get days

```
df['date_1'] - df['date_2']
```

i get the error 
**TypeError: incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation**

Answer (score 4):

Need convert columns to `datetime`s:

```
df['date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_1'])
df['date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_2'])
```

Or:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

And then:

```
df['days'] = (df['date_1'] - df['date_2']).dt.days
```